# Форматирование байтов

Tags: python

Есть число `3454`. Как его преобразовать и отформатировать чтобы получилось `b'3454'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes):

```
bytes(str(3454), 'ascii')
```

Кодировки тут: [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Так как тут только цифры, `ascii` подойдёт. Впрочем подойдет и любая другая.